# Bootstrap vue Tab component is not working when an Index is used to navigate trough the tabs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Why this very simple bootstrap vue script does not work, on pressing the toggle button it just does not increment the value tabIndex.

- tabIndex starts in 0, user presses tabIndex, value still 0.
- if tabIndex is removed from disabled attribute it will work but it will not follow the purpose I require.
  Script can be seen here:
  https://jsfiddle.net/Xarina/tkoyph4x/1/

  ```
  <div id="app">
    <b-card no-block>{{tabIndex}}
     <b-tabs small card ref="tabs" v-model="tabIndex">
       <b-tab title="General">
         I'm the first fading tab
       </b-tab>
       <b-tab title="Edit profile" :disabled="tabIndex < 1">
         I'm the second tab
       </b-tab>
       <b-tab title="Premium Plan" :disabled="tabIndex < 2">
         Sibzamini!
       </b-tab>
     </b-tabs>
    </b-card>

   <button @click="tabIndex++">
    Click to toggle disable
   </button>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a custom class to each `tab` using `title-item-class` according to the `tabIndex`:

```js
window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ tabs: [], tabCounter: 0, disabled: false, tabIndex: 0 }),
});
```

```css
.disabledTab .nav-link {  pointer-events: none; color: #666666; }
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfi0ll@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-card no-block>{{tabIndex}}
    <b-tabs small card ref="tabs" v-model="tabIndex">
      <b-tab title="General">I'm the first fading tab</b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Edit profile" :title-item-class="{ disabledTab: tabIndex < 1 }">I'm the second tab</b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Premium Plan" :title-item-class="{ disabledTab: tabIndex < 2 }">Sibzamini!</b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
  <button @click="tabIndex++">Click to toggle disable</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah I think I might have to follow that approach, I was thinking there was some bootstrap vue thing I can easily do. Thaaank you

Comment: The issue is that when a tab is disabled, its status doesn't change when the state tabIndex changes, hence it's logically out of the tabs array and clicking the button doesn't change the index above 0 since the array of tabs only has this one active tab. The above was suggested after not finding a clear way from bootstrap-vue and it delivers a similar solution to your problem.

Comment: Yeah I tried, at first it did not work, but I made a mistake and then IT WORKED, didn't know about pointer-events: none; Thaaanks!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you can't swap to a tab that's disabled. And the check happens before the index is disabled, meaning it will set the tab index back to 0.

You can get around this by using two data properties, one for disabling the tabs, and one for the `<b-tabs>` v-model. Then updating the property using for disabling first, and the v-model property in the a `$nextTick` callback.

In the example below i utilize a `watcher` to set the second property automatically when the other changes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      currentTab: 0,
      disabledTabIndex: 0
    }
  },
  watch: {
    disabledTabIndex(newVal) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.currentTab = newVal;
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-card no-block>
    Current tab: {{ currentTab }}
    <b-tabs small card ref="tabs" v-model="currentTab">
      <b-tab title="General">I'm the first fading tab</b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Edit profile" :disabled="disabledTabIndex < 1">
        I'm the second tab
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Premium Plan" :disabled="disabledTabIndex < 2">
        Sibzamini!
      </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
  <button @click="disabledTabIndex++">Click to toggle disable</button>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting solution, I used the other one already. But it makes sense. thanks